# Programatically created user - wrong password when logging in?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, password

I have to make a cron job that once a day creates users from a file on the server. The script works fine, but, the users it generates can't log in (only local for now, not live).

Here is the code:

```
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

$customer = $customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->setMediqCustomerId($mediqId);
$customer->setEmail($email);
$customer->setFirstname($name);
$customer->setPassword('Password123');
$customer->save();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? When trying to log in with user created with this, it says that the password is wrong.

PS I know not to use OM like this. I just wanted to test if I can even make users in code like this.

Any help is more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code to create customer programmatically

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer   = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail("email@email.com"); 
        $customer->setFirstname("First Name");
        $customer->setLastname("Last name");
        $customer->setPassword("password");

        // Save data
        $customer->save();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to this and try, I tried this its working fine at my end:

```
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

$customer = $customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->setEmail($email);
$customer->setFirstname($firstName);
$customer->setLastname($lastName);
$customer->setPassword('Password123');
$customer->save();
```

I think you are not using LastName which is required when creating customer.

Or try to create customer using Magento 2 REST APIs

```
    $userData = array("username" => "adminurser", "password" => "password");
    $ch = curl_init("http://domain.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);


    $customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            "email" => "user@example.com",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1
        ],
        "password" => "Demo1234"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init("http://domain.com/rest/V1/customers");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Comment: Tested, still the same. The thing is, that the user is created, but the password seems to be wrong when trying to login. Any ideas what else it could be?

Comment: Try to create customer using REST API, I have updated answer please have a look.

Comment: Figured it out.. The store_id and website_id were both being set to 0, instead of 1. Idk why tho..

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. The website_id and store_id were both being set to 0  instead of 1